# How do I plot the mean instead of the median with geom_boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

for some inane reason, I need to create a boxplot where the middle line is the **mean** instead of the median. I checked stackoverflow already and found examples of *adding* a mean line, but not exactly what I need. I tried using stat_smooth but no dice. Any ideas?

*code below:*

```
dust <- c(4.5, 3.7, 5, 5.2, 8.5, 6.6, 4.7, 5, 5.7, 4.3, 2.3, 7.6, 5.2, 
          6, 8.7, 7.5, 7.7, 11, 9, 6.5, 8.7, 5, 2.2, 7.5, 7.5, 3.5)

wind <- c("Present", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", 
  "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Present", "Absent", "Absent", 
  "Present", "Present", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", "Absent", 
  "Absent", "Present", "Absent", "Present", "Absent", "Absent", 
  "Absent", "Present")

df <- data.frame(dust,wind)

plot <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=wind,y=dust))+geom_boxplot()+stat_smooth()

plot
```

Comment: geom_boxplot can take more detailed args like middle (i.e., the average value), ymin, lower, etc. check out ?geom_boxplot

Comment: `geom_boxplot(middle = mean(dust))`. Also, why `stat_smooth`? What does it do?

Comment: @RuiBarradas don't forget the `aes`: `geom_boxplot(aes(middle = mean(dust)))`

Comment: @neilfws Yes, thanks. Sorry, I mislead the OP.

Comment: @Chris With two upvotes so far, this seems to be a question that deserves an answer for future users to refer to. Wouldn't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: there you are @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

#### 1. Using middle

The easiest is to simply call:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(y = dust, x = wind)) + 
        geom_boxplot(aes(middle = mean(dust))
```

#### 2. Using fatten = NULL

You can also take advantage of the `fatten` parameter in `geom_boxplot()`. This controls the thickness of the median line. If we set it to `NULL`, then it will not plot a median line, and we can insert a line for the mean using `stat_summary`.

```
plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(y = dust, x = wind)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fatten = NULL) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..),
               width = 0.75, size = 1, linetype = "solid")
print(plot)
```

Output using `fatten = NULL`

[image]

As you can see, the above method plots just fine, but when you evaluate the code it will output some warning messages because `fatten` is not really expected to take a `NULL` value.

The upside is that this method is possibly a bit more flexible, as we are essentially "erasing" the median line and adding in whatever we want. For example, we could also choose to keep the median, and add the mean as a dashed line.

Comment: This answer is not correct. aes middle does not have the desired effect.

Comment: Ah, I just checked and it looks like you are right! It looks like this solution no longer works with current versions of ggplot2. I'll edit this post with a correct solution later today.

Answer (score 5):

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x = wind, ymin = min(dust), lower = quantile(dust, .25), 
      middle = mean(dust), upper = quantile(dust, .75),
      ymax = max(dust)
    ), stat = "identity"
  )
```

Comment: I receive the following error when I want to rn the code:
 Can't draw more than one boxplot per group. Did you forget aes(group = ...)?