# ggplot geom_boxplot middle aes no effect

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to plot boxplot with ggplot2. I want to change the middle to mean.

I know people have asked similar questions before, but I'm asking this because the solution didn't work for me. Specifically I followed the first solution in this accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50112195/4720244)

This is what I did with mpg test data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = cty, middle = mean(cty))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

It has no effect.

graph plotting mean:
[image]

graph plotting with default median:
[image]

Can anyone help to point out what I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Actually if you look closely at the answer that you linked, the `middle = mean()` call is inside the `geom_boxplot(aes())` call not the `ggplot` call.  Try shifting it to the `boxplot` call as I don't think the `middle` specification exists for `ggplot` itself.

Comment: `aes` can be called inside `geom_boxplot` or `ggplot`(it's shared by all layouts in this case). I've tried both though it really shouldn't make a difference, and it didn't.

Comment: another option is that the mean and median are very similar in all cases. Try this: tapply(mpg$cty, mpg$class, summary)

Comment: @bob1 You're right that most of them are quite close. But at least one class, subcompact, has a very different mean(20.37) than median(19). I tried to use other functions (e.g. max) and none has any effect. Start to think the linked solution is wrong. Any idea what would be a solution without creating a new df just for this?

Comment: @EJ2015 If you are still looking for solutions, I just answered a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684585/override-lower-upper-etc-in-boxplot-while-grouping/53699288). Solution 2 might be modified to suit your use case.

Answer (score 4):

Messing around with another dataset, `mtcars`, shows the same thing, defining `middle` doesn't change it. And that one has some larger differences in mean to median. Another option is using `stat_summary`, although I can't get the points function to work just right, and had to tweak it to not get a `arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0` error.

```
BoxMeanQuant <- function(x) {
    v <- c(min(x), quantile(x, 0.25), mean(x), quantile(x, 0.75), max(x))
    names(v) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
    v
  }

mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = cty)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = BoxMeanQuant, geom = "boxplot")
```

[image]

Compared to the normal `geom_boxplot`, which is not using the defined `middle`.

```
mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = cty)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(middle = mean(cty)))
```

[image]

This is what I was using to plot the outliers as points, but they're different from whatever the default for `geom_boxplot` is. You can adjust as necessary. Without using the `if-else` it would throw an error.

```
BoxMeanQuant <- function(x) {
  v <- c(quantile(x, 0.1), quantile(x, 0.25), mean(x), quantile(x, 0.75), quantile(x, 0.9))
  names(v) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  v
}

outliers <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) > 5) {
  subset(x, x < quantile(x, 0.1) | quantile(x, 0.9) < x)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = class, y = cty)) +
stat_summary(fun.data = BoxMeanQuant, geom = "boxplot") +
stat_summary(fun.y = outliers, geom = "point")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing how to do this with `stat_summary`.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I had to create a summary df to do this. It is not what I was originally looking for, but it works.

```
df <- mpg %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarize(ymin = min(cty), ymax = max(cty), lower = quantile(cty, 0.25), upper = quantile(cty, 0.75), middle = mean(cty)) 

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(class)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, lower = lower, upper = upper, middle = middle), stat = 'identity')
```