# change median to mean in ggpubr - r

Tags: r, boxplot, ggpubr

I have a ggpubr boxplot and I want the middle line to be the mean and not the median, does anyone has an idea how to do it?
What I have right now is the median as the line and the mean as a dot, I want to remove the median and add the mean as the line.

```
> head(my_data)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  SHM_level Batch_number Isotypes
      <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>   
1        11            4 IgM     
2         3            4 IgM     
3         5            4 IgM     
4        20            4 IgM     
5         5            4 IgM     
6         5            4 IgM
```

my code:

```
 #perform test
compare_means(SHM_level ~ Isotypes, data = my_data, group.by = "Batch_number")
#plot    
p1<- ggboxplot(my_data, x = "Batch_number", y = "SHM_level",
                  color = "Isotypes", palette = "jco", add = "mean")+ggtitle("DLN")+ylim(0,40)+
      stat_compare_means(aes(group = Isotypes), label = "p.signif")+xlab("Batch number")+
      ylab("SHM level")
```

plot:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Related post using ggplot, not ggpubr, but can be adapted. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50112033/680068

Comment: I sew that one but I don't know how to adapt it to ggpubr.

Comment: Maybe just use ggplot, not ggpubr?